# How i open a web site in chrome with a pre-defined command

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

When i open **"youtube"**, in the "nav-bar" i have a **"trending" link**, i would like to **hide it**.

I usually use

`document.getElementById('trending-guide-item').style.display='none';`

in the console to do it, and i was wondering **if its there any option to do it automatically** when i launch youtube,

Any sujestion?

I already tried to do in with a shortcut, and i don't know if i can do it with a plugin, i only did some "alerts" in chrome...

¡Thanks for all!

Comment: i am pretty sure you are looking for something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something as simple as that you could also use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en). Stylebot is a Chrome extension that allows you to inject CSS rules into any website.